# LF Versus CRLF Line Endings in Windows Batch Files

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

I have a mixed Ubuntu, OS X and Windows git repository containing `.bat` and `.cmd` files targeted for use on Windows 7 and greater. `core.autocrlf` is set to `input`, and so post-`git checkout` these files have `LF` line endings in my working directory instead of the `CRLF` line-endings I started out with.

Will this cause problems with windows batch execution? In what cases might this difference be significant? I have yet to see any issue but wish to code defensively.

Comment: Why are you using `core.autocrlf=input`?  Do you have a `.gitattributes`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can override this for batch files using the following `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.bat text eol=crlf
```

From [Is it safe to write batch files with Unix line endings?](https://serverfault.com/questions/429594/is-it-safe-to-write-batch-files-with-unix-line-endings)  There is a comment about labels not working correctly with LF.  The fix is easy enough.